# OpenGL fails when resizing buffer

Tags: c++, c, opengl, exc-bad-access

I need to update an array of pixels to the screen every frame. It works initially, however when I try to resize the screen it glitches and eventually throws `EXC_BAD_ACCESS 1`. I already checked that the buffer is allocated to the correct size before every frame, however it does not seem to affect the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>

unsigned char *buffer = NULL;
int width = 400, height = 400;
unsigned int screenTexture;

void Display()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y+=4) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            buffer[(x + y * width) * 3] = 255;
        }
    }

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    // This function results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS 1, although the buffer is always correctly allocated
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glBegin (GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2i(0,    0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2i(width,0);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2i(width,height);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2i(0,    height);
    glEnd ();

    glFlush();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void Resize(int w, int h)
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
    buffer = (unsigned char *)realloc(buffer, sizeof(unsigned char) * width * height * 3);

    if (!buffer) {
        printf("Error Reallocating buffer\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(width, height);
    glutCreateWindow("Rasterizer");
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    glutReshapeFunc(Resize);

    glGenTextures(1, &screenTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, screenTexture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    buffer = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * width * height * 3);

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

After resizing the screen does not display properly either:
[image]

What is causing this problem? The code compiles and runs you just have to link GLUT and OpenGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @genpfault mentioned, OpenGL reads 4 bytes per pixel instead of your assumption of 3.

Instead of changing `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`, you can also change your code to the correct assumption of 4 bytes per pixel via a simple `struct`:

```
struct pixel {
    unsigned char r, g, b;
    unsigned char unused;
};
```

Then, instead of using the magic constant 3, you can use the much clearer `sizeof(struct pixel)`. This makes it easier to read and to convey the intent of the code, and it doesn't result in any extra code (as the structure is "effectively" an array of 4 bytes).

Comment: I tried setting the unpack alignment to 1 so it shouldn't matter but Ill try that too

Answer (score 0):

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
                                                         ^^^^^^
```

`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` defaults to `4`, not `1`.  So OpenGL will read *4* bytes for every pixel, not the 3 that you're assuming.

Set `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to `1` using `glPixelStorei()`.

Comment: `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` is the alignment per row, not per pixel, isn't it?

Comment: Setting the unpack alignment does not help but aligning the data to 4 bytes worked

Comment: @StasJaro - FYI, sometimes you can look at an image and tell right away what the general problem is.  The image you have has the  "staircase" effect -- once you see that, it is almost a guarantee that the image was not aligned.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you found something that works, but I don't think the problem was properly diagnosed. I believe the biggest issue is in the way you initialize your texture data here:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y+=4) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        buffer[(x + y * width) * 3] = 255;
    }
}
```

This only sets data in every 4th row, and then only for every 3rd byte within those rows. To initialize all the data to white, you need to increment the row number (`y`) by 1 instead of 4, and set all 3 components inside the loop:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        buffer[(x + y * width) * 3    ] = 255;
        buffer[(x + y * width) * 3 + 1] = 255;
        buffer[(x + y * width) * 3 + 2] = 255;
    }
}
```

You also need to set `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to 1:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

This controls the row alignment (not the pixel alignment, as suggested in a couple other answers). The default value for `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` is 4. But with 3 bytes per pixel in the `GL_RGB` format you are using, the size of a row is only a multiple of 4 bytes if the number of pixels is a multiple of 4. So for tightly packed rows with 3 bytes/pixel, the value needs to be set to 1.

Comment: Actually I already wrote a software 3d rasterizer however it wouldn't make any sense to post the entire thing here so the texture data simply loads a RED (byte1[r],byte2[g],byte3[b]) stripe pattern for simplicity. (which is cleared with memset 0 on resize)